# I want to make a GUI but i get this error: self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew") AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'grid'

Tags: python-3.x, class, tkinter, grid

Sorry about the layout of this question, my first time working with stackoverflow posts. 
I want to make a GUI for Tic Tac Toe (Game menu). And have the abillity to put buttons where ever i want in the GUI so i used Grid.

```
import tkinter as tk

LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)

class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (MainWindow, Game, Difficulty):
            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Welcom to TIC TAC TOE", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Start",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Game))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Diffeculty",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Difficulty))
        button2.pack()

        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Quit", command=self.Quit)
        button3.pack()

        label1 = tk.Label(self, text="Made by VindictaOG")
        label1.pack()

    def Quit(self):
            exit()


class Game(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="New Game")
        button1.pack()

        button2= tk.Button(self, text="Back to homescreen",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MainWindow))
        button2.pack()


class Difficulty(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="1V1", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MainWindow))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to homescreen",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Game))
        button2.pack()

gui = SeaofBTCapp() 
gui.mainloop()
```

But when i use grid i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ivar/PycharmProjects/J1B2Afvink6/BKE.py", line 82, in <module>
    gui = SeaofBTCapp()
  File "/home/ivar/PycharmProjects/J1B2Afvink6/BKE.py", line 27, in __init__
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
TypeError: wm_grid() got an unexpected keyword argument 'row'
```

I tried it with pack but that would not work, does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: please format the code

Comment: i made it according to format i think. Thanks for notifing me.

Comment: Change `self.frame.grid(...)` to `frame.grid(...)`.

Comment: This code doesn't give the error you say it does after editing. You've left out the definition of `LARGE_FONT`.

Comment: Wait what? LARGE_FONT is in there isnt it? Im sorry. I was sure i just copy pasted my code as in PyCharm but apparently not. I have LARGE_FOND deffined after importing tkinter

Comment: Should inherit from `tk.Frame` instead of `tk.Tk` for `MainWindow`, `Game` and `Difficulty`.  Also `StartPage` is not defined.

Comment: Thanks a lot that solved it. I used to do (tk.Tk, tk.Frame) but that didnt work. But (tk.Frame, tk.Tk) works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should inherit from tk.Frame instead of tk.Tk for MainWindow, Game and Difficulty. Also StartPage is not defined. @acw1668

Using (tk.Frame, tk.Tk) instead of just (tk.Tk) solved the problem.